# Setting a Frame Size and Location in Tkinter

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I am trying to set a frame-size and the location of the frame (master widget) in Tkinter. Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091548/centering-and-size-a-windows-frame-in-tkinter-class-python), I added this to my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ctypes
user = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = (user.GetSystemMetrics(0), user.GetSystemMetrics(1), user.GetSystemMetrics(2), user.GetSystemMetrics(3))

class GetWord:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry("%s+%s+%s+%s" % (screensize[0], screensize[1], screensize[2], screensize[3]))
        # I added the above in, but not sure how it works
        self.frame = Frame(master, width = screensize[0], height = screensize[1])
        self.frame.grid()
```

However, when doing this I get a `TclError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File #file path, line 39, in <module>
    f = GetWord(root)
  File #file path, line 8, in __init__
    master.geometry("%s+%s+%s+%s" % (screensize[0], screensize[1], screensize[2], screensize[3]))
  File "C:\Python2.7.3\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1534, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
TclError: bad geometry specifier "1366+768+17+17"
```

I call the class like this:

```
root = Tk(className='derp')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
f = GetWord(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I fix this? I want to have the frame start off in the center of the screen and start at a specific window size (right now it's full-screen but I will change that later on). Thanks!

Comment: Should be `"%sx%s+%s+%s"` for width, height, left, right (note `x` instead of `+`)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Oh, small mistake. You should add that as an answer. Also, how can I center the frame?

Comment: You are already filling up the user's whole screen with the frame, I don't see a need to center it then.

Comment: @Siddharth I was just using the full-screen as an example. In my actual program, it will be about `w/4` and `h/4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Need to use the letter "x" instead of "+"

```
master.geometry("%sx%sx%sx%s" % (screensize[0], screensize[1], screensize[2], screensize[3]))
```

Comment: I'm generally going to use `screensize[0]/2` and `screensize[1]/2` as the parameters. How can I center the window in the middle of the screen?