# How to move the entire window to a place on the screen (Tkinter, Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title says it all. How to move the entire window to a place on the screen using tkinter. This should be moving the root frame.

Comment: use [.geometry() method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11093235/4279)

Answer (score 10):

Use the [geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method of the root (or any Toplevel) window. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("+200+400") # places the window at 200,400 on the screen
```

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
from tkinter import Tk

main=Tk()
main.geometry('+100+200')
main.mainloop()
```

or do it with function :

```
def change_position(root_variable,x,y):
    root_variable.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x,y))
```

and use :`change_position(main,500,400)`

edit: added dot for format